# Scylla error on FThunk import (manually unpacking UPX)

Tags: x64dbg, packers, upx

I'm trying to practice on manual unpacking starting from UPX.

I'm using putty.exe x64
This is what I'm doing:

- upx -o putty_packed.exe putty.exe
- Disable Dynamic base (ASLR) using CFF Explorer on putty_packed.exe
- using x64dbg I found the last jmp before the code is unpacked
  [image: last jump before unpack]
- the strings are not visible (packed)
- step over, now the strings are visible (it should confirm that the code is unpacked)
  [image: first unpacked instruction]
- Plugins -> OllyDumpEx -> Get RIP as OEP -> Dump
  (I tried to set the MEM_WRITE enabled or disabled on the UPX1 section too)
- Plugins -> Scylla -> IAT Autosearch (both yes and not on the advanced search popup) -> Get Imports
- The imports list shows an error on the FThunk
  [image: scylla import error]

What am I doing wrong?
The same happens using autoruns x32 (using x32dbg)

The only solution I've found for now, is to use the "Delete tree node" against the red icon tree node.

Thanks in advance.
Ryuk